# Rewrite Rules not working when moved code to a subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have been using the following rules to pass query strings in my URLs on my development domain on same server and it was working.

Working code on DOMAIN1
URL: http://DOMAIN1.com/billing/renew.php?invoice_no=XXX

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^billing/renew/invoice/([^/]*)$ /billing/renew.php?invoice_no=$1 [L]
```

However when I deployed it to live domain in a subdirectory "beta" it is not working.
Both domains are on same server and host configurations are same.
Overrides are allowed to make sure htaccess is working. Only difference is live domain works on https protocol and a rewrite rule is defined in host config to redirect all not https traffic to https.

I have placed httacess file in beta directory on live server.

NON-Working code on DOMAIN2
URL: "https://DOMAIN2.com/beta/billing/renew.php?invoice_no=XXX"

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /beta/

RewriteRule ^billing/renew/invoice/([^/]*)$ /billing/renew.php?invoice_no=$1 [L]
```

Also tried

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^beta/billing/renew/invoice/([^/]*)$ /beta/billing/renew.php?invoice_no=$1 [L]
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the rule's target a relative URI so that the base can be applied to it. Either that, or add the base to the absolute URI:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /beta/

RewriteRule ^billing/renew/invoice/([^/]*)$ billing/renew.php?invoice_no=$1 [L]
# No "/" here ------------------------------^
```

Or

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^billing/renew/invoice/([^/]*)$ /beta/billing/renew.php?invoice_no=$1 [L]
# Add the "/beta" here ---------------------^
```

Comment: Sorry for being a pain, the real issue was file name was renew.php and server is somehow using it as simple get request.
If I change file name to Renew.php it works fine, dont know why it is happening but my rules are working now so thanks for help.